# Flexslider videos not playing in Safari 11

Tags: video, safari

Just noticed that video clips I have in Flexslider which have always played have ceased doing so in Safari 11. Slider displays the backup image for each slide (as it would on a mobile device). Still working fine in chrome and ff. Has anyone experienced / solved this? Thanks!

example: http://www.elanartists.com/4.0/showcase/

Comment: video tag i'm using for the slide:

<video width="100%" height="100%" poster="http://www.elanartists.com/4.0/images/showcase/showcase-main.jpg" preload="auto" loop autoplay muted>
<source src="http://www.elanartists.com/4.0/video/source_live-thin.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="http://www.elanartists.com/4.0/video/source_live-thin.ogv" type="video/ogg">
<img src="http://www.elanartists.com/4.0/images/showcase/showcase-main.jpg" title="No video playback capabilities" alt="Video thumb" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

Answer (score 1):

I think it´s with the new safari "autoplay video" blocking to provide video ads from running. You can disable that direct in the safari options under "websites" or you go to the URL with your video and right-click on the URL. There you can take preferences for this URL and you can grant rights for automatic playback. In my research so far it´s also possible to tag the video with the HTML `<video muted>` syntax so the new Safari 11 will play it automatically.

Comment: thanks for checking. strangely i had already tried changing the preferences for the website with no luck. already had "muted" in the code too. can't seem to get it to autoplay.

Comment: just added the video tag i'm using to the original post.

Comment: Thank u so much! This answer helped me a lot! :)